# Regex to identify duplicate string arrays

Tags: c#, regex

I have an array of strings.  They are actually file directories.

It might like look like:

```
Documents/jdeer-12345
Documents/jdoe-12345
Documents/fflintstone-01224
Documents/reports
```

First, I identify all the files will 5 digits at the end:

```
 string regexPattern = @".*\-\d{5}";
```

I use that to find all the directories that match

```
results = directories.Where(path => regexPattern.IsMatch(path).ToList();
```

So I've currently removed the reports directory and am left with an array of strings.

```
Documents/jdeer-12345
Documents/jder-12345
Documents/fflintstone-01224
```

I trying to identify distinct 5 digit numbers at the end of the file and keep one record. For instance, I don't care if jdeer and jder are different, but if that record has the same id, I need to flag and delete it.

Final result might keep first record with same number id
    Documents/jdeer-12345
    Documents/fflintstone-01224

1. How can I just regex to identify alike strings in an array.
2. How can I then remove one record.

Comment: How about using *Distinct(IEqualityComparer<T>)*?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your regex to split input into groups:

```
var splitter = new Regex("^.+-(?<num>\\d{5})$");
```

then apply LINQ query

```
var result = directories.Select(l => splitter.Match(l))
    .Where(m => m.Success)
    .Select(m => new {num = m.Groups["num"].Value, src = m.Value})
    .GroupBy(x => x.num)
    .Select(g => g.First().src)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be Regex?  I'm not sure it will operate across separate array entries like that, remembering what it's encountered before...  A simple foreach loop like this should do it:

```
List<string> finalResults = new List<string>();
List<int> idsEncountered = new List<int>();
foreach (string dir in results)
{
    int id = int.Parse(dir.Substring(s.Length - 5));
    if (!idsEncountered.Contains(id))
    {
        idsEncountered.Add(id);
        finalResults.Add(dir);
    }
}
```

Note that this would keep the first string it finds with that id.

Good luck!

Comment: Doesn't have to be. I was just going to do some standard loop, then I got thinking maybe there was some other way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Regex for this.  I just wrote a simple method that dedupes on the "id" of each file, and removes anything that does not contain an "id":

```
public static IEnumerable<string> DeDupeFileList(List<string> files)
{
    List<string> ids = new List<string>();
    foreach(string f in files)
    {
        var split = f.Split('-');
        if(split.Length > 1)
        {
            if(!ids.Contains(split[1]))
            {
                ids.Add(split[1]);
                yield return f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that my solution splits on the `-` character.  This most likely is not a problem since your Regex pattern used it as well.  Just an FYI.

Made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cde05j)